# Is the medical tag too broad and ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, tags

Earlier today I was reviewing tag wiki edits and came across a suggested edit adding this to the [medical](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) tag:

> For questions about routine physical examinations.

While I am familiar with the concept of *going for a medical*, at least here in the UK, this is only really used when doing a medical examination for occupational, insurance or driving reasons.

If there is to be a tag for this, I feel that using `medical` on the Medical Sciences Stack Exchange is not the best course of action. Perhaps `medical-examination` would be appropriate.

In fact, the [medical](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) tag might be too broad for use on the Medical Sciences Stack Exchange! Currently it only has two questions; one about clinical rotations in the US and one about measuring blood pressure.

How should we use or modify the [medical](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two uses of the tag:

https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical

One of them may use the term in the context of the tag edit suggestion, as a routine medical examination. The other is definitely not. However, the US term for the same is usually a "physical" instead (there may be differences in what is performed at a typical UK medical vs a US physical; a US physical applies both to the cases you mention as well as to a type of routine office visit with no particular symptoms to discuss). I'm not sure whether the "medical" terminology is familiar to other speakers of English outside the UK.

I'd suggest just getting rid of the tag entirely.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I think that removing the tag is the way to go.

Comment: @Chris Since there were only two usages and neither seemed helpful to me, I just went and edited them out. I believe that means the tag will disappear during maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was wondering how we went about getting rid of it!

Comment: @Chris Moderators can also do it, I believe, though I haven't messed with them much myself. But in a case like this there is little need to bother them with it, given that fixing the issue is easy and only bumps two questions.

Comment: @BryanKrause If there's a way for mods to delete a tag, I'm unaware of it. I believe I would have to ask the CM team to delete it.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yeah - I see the merge and synonym options only. We'll see what happens, I think it should poof now that there are no questions using it.

Comment: (note: the tag is now gone. Victory for all involved)

Comment: @BryanKrause I just dropped in to tell you that you were right. :-)